# Will my PhoneGap application be rejected if it downloads HTML and places it in a screen?

Tags: android, html, ios, cordova

One of my client's requirements is to be able to dynamically update content within their mobile app. Will our PhoneGap app be rejected if it downloads a HTML file upon launch and appends/replaces content in the app?

Comment: This isn't iOS land.  The only thing Google checks for is malware.  Other than that, you can do what you want.

Comment: @GabeSechan What about iOS land? Will Apple reject it? This app is for iPhone and Android phones.

Comment: iOS has several pages of rules about whats allowed and isn't, including content, not being allowed to compete with Apple now or in the future, and a hundred other rules all of which are interpreted inconsistently.  So I have no clue.  Android isn't like that, pretty much the only thing you can't go is have a virus or steal passwords.  There's really no acceptance process other than a virus scan.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks for the detailed response, Gabe!

Answer (score 0):

You're basically describing a hybrid app. This alone will not fail your app.